# PHP: Need help downloading images from URL that contains parameters

Tags: php, image, download

**My Question:
Using PHP how do you download an image from a URL that has its size set using parameters?**

Here is an example of the images I need to download:
http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Asset_441005?wid=2000

I get this error:
Warning: fopen(images/Asset_441005?wid=2000): failed to open stream: No error

If I remove the wid parameter the image downloads fine, but at 400px wide which is too small to use:
http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Asset_441005

Here is my code that does not work:

```
<?php

$url_to_image = 'http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Asset_441005?wid=2000';

$ch = curl_init($url_to_image);

$my_save_dir = 'images/';
$filename = basename($url_to_image);
$complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;

$fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Here is the code that does work, but the image is too small for me to use:

```
<?php

    $url_to_image = 'http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Asset_441005';

    $ch = curl_init($url_to_image);

    $my_save_dir = 'images/';
    $filename = basename($url_to_image);
    $complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;

    $fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    ?>
```

Comment: What makes you think that such a get parameter will result in a "sized" image? The error message indicates that the server side follows the primitive approach to take the string following the base URL and interpreting it as file name. No resizing logic to be seen there.

Comment: You might want to check what name the file is being stored in the images folder and if the `$complete_save_loc` is using the same name.

Comment: If you open both those URL's you will see what it is doing and what I am trying to download. Large image: http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Asset_441005?wid=2000   and small image: http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Asset_441005   I simply want to download the large image.

Comment: @arkascha To clarify, the supplier has it setup so you can request an image at any width between 1px and 2000px by changing the wid parameter. I guess they are resizing the image somehow?

Comment: @Vishnu667 If I remove the wid parameter it saves as a file called Asset_441005.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted your description such that you receive that error from the remote side.

Comment: If you can help in any way it would be much appreciated. Perhaps I need to use something other than php?

Comment: If you only want the file name without the query parameters you can try `$filename = basename(parse_url($url_to_image)['path']);`

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out using the following code:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Asset_441005?wid=2000');
$myfile = fopen("test.jpg", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $file);
fclose($myfile);


?>
```

Now simple have to get the file name instead of using test.jpg